# Shuffle Two Different Arrays In Different Orders

Tags: javascript

I have two decks of cards:

```
var cardDeck = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K", "A"];
var player1Deck = shuffle(cardDeck);
var player2Deck = shuffle(cardDeck);
```

That are shuffled:

```
function shuffle(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};
```

However, they both shuffle in the same order:

```
player1Deck = [1, 2, "A", 5, 4, 8, "J", 9, 6, 10, "Q", 7, 3, "K"];
player2Deck = [1, 2, "A", 5, 4, 8, "J", 9, 6, 10, "Q", 7, 3, "K"];
```

Instead, I would like the decks to shuffle differently to be something like:

```
player1Deck = [1, 2, "A", 5, 4, 8, "J", 9, 6, 10, "Q", 7, 3, "K"];
player2Deck = ["A", 3, 1, 8, 4, 5, "K", 7, "Q", 10, 6, 9, 2, "J"];
```

If possible, I would like to keep this in Javascript only.

Comment: they look like 2 arrays ...but are the same one...read up on *javascript prototypal inheritance*

Comment: Read up on the Fisher Yates shuffle. Do this twice, once for each array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your shuffle method does a inline shuffling, so the same instance is returned.

So pass a copy of the original array to the shuffle method, for which you can use the `slice(0)` method

```
var cardDeck = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K", "A"];
var player1Deck = shuffle(cardDeck.slice(0));
var player2Deck = shuffle(cardDeck.slice(0));
```

Comment: `.slice(0)` can as well be `.slice()`.

Comment: You're right about the reason, but I think it would be better style to copy to (and return) a new array WITHIN the function.

Comment: @SMcCrohan yes... that also can be done... I think the shuffle method was designed along the lines of the sort method...